# Converting literal to RDD for subsequent Cartesian Product

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Cannot find in the documentation how the result of below:

```
 val DIM_Key_Max = rddA.map(x => (x._1)).max
```

can be subsequently converted to a single entry RDD for JOINing with another RDD, or rather cartesian product.

Nowhere I can see that. Who can help?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are asking. How do you create rddA before getting the max. What is the real issue here ?

Comment: You are getting something wrong here. max will not return an RDD which can be joined later. For example.

Comment: I have the max value as I want from an RDD. It works fine and I want to use it as an offset for another column in a DF which gets converted from an RDD. SO, not sure what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` returns a single object. To turn it into a single entry RDD, use `parallelize`:

```
sc.parallelize(List(DIM_Key_Max))
```

This returns an RDD with a single entry that can be used e.g. as an argument to `cartesian`.

Comment: It was so simple I overlooked this! Thanks

Comment: @thebluephantom can you review your old questions as well please and accept the answers that solved your issues. You seem to have a bunch of unaccepted answers. Thanks !

Comment: But I do not agree with the answers always

Comment: @thebluephantom then you'll need to comment on those answers why the proposed solution doesn't work for you so the answers try to give a better answer. This is what the site is about :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting something wrong here. max will not retrun an RDD which can be joined with another RDD.

```
val rdd=sc.parallelize(Array((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))).map(x=>x._1).max
rdd
rdd: Int = 5
rdd.getClass
res2: Class[Int] = int
```

Comment: So, that's my whole point. I want to make an RDD from this Int.

Comment: The answer below is what I want